# Put not editable text with quotation marks in a string variable

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, quotation-marks

I'm writing a function to scrape data from a website using xpath strings like this:

`//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[14]`

As Obvious, when I assign this string to a variable I get a syntax error due to the presence of the quotation marks.
I already know some ways to manually correct the text and avoid errors.
My question is if there's a way to put the text into a variable "as it is".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem at all assigning this string to a variable "as is". E.g. write the string(s) into a table and read it from a recordset.

But if you want to hard-code the string in your VBA source code, you need to escape the quotes by duplicating them.

```vb
Const xPath As String = "//*[@id=""mw-content-text""]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[14]"
```